# Button not submitting form but submitting a value

Tags: html, node.js, button

I want to have a button that doesnt submit a form, but does submit its value. For example,

```
<html>
 <body>
  <form action="/home" method="post">
   <button value="1" type="button" name="b1>Test</button>
   <button value="2" type="submit" name="b2">Test2</button>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

when i press the first one, it wont submit the form, but it will submit its value. In node.js i will have.

```
app.post('/home', (req, res) => {
 var button1 = req.body.b1;
 var button2 = req.body.b2;
 console.log(button1);
 console.log(button2);
});
```

when i press button1 it will not submit anything, and wont redirect you. When you press button2, it will redirect you and will console.log both button1 and button2.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: first, the number 1 coming up in the console, then, the number 2 coming up in the console. After pressing the second button

Comment: What about the first button?

Comment: The first button will send the value of 1 to node.js when the user presses it in the variable button1, the second button will send the value of 2 to the variable button2 along with redirecting the user to '/home'

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a hidden input would do it?

```
 <input value="1" type="hidden" name="b1>
```

Comment: This makes the button invisible. I want to make the button submit the value but not submit the form.

Comment: Did you add the hidden input, or replace the button?